# Get user key press or a command (C#)

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input

I'm making a basic console app.
I basically want to wait for a particular key press like F1, F2 ... or if non is pressed, the user can type in the entire command. And the problem I'm facing is that when I call `Console.ReadKey()` it always suppresses the first character in the user's input. This will break the console history and the command itself. I want to read only functional keys, but when the user wants to type a normal command like 'echo' i don't want the 'e' to be treated as a keypress but as an entire command.
Examples:

- User presses F1 which means they don't want to input a command so the F1 logic will execute and the user will be able to make a new interaction (command or key press)
- User presses 'e' which means they want to type an entire command like
  'echo' so the program will wait for a next line (enter)

  Code

  ```
       public string[] Input()
       {
           Console.Write(Core.commandChar);
           var KP = Console.ReadKey();

           if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.F1)
           {
               inputs = new string[] { "echo", "test", "" };
               return inputs;
           }


           inputs = (KP.KeyChar+Console.ReadLine()).Split(' ');
           return inputs;
       }
  ```

Is there a way to pull this off?

Comment: In your example it sounds like you need to keep hold of the `"e"` and prepend the result of `Console.ReadLine()` `"cho"` with the `"e"` to get the full command `"echo"`

Comment: Add your code to your question. `Console.ReadKey()` doesn't "suppress" anything.

Comment: Sure. Use ReadKey(), if the character is an FX key then do action otherwise add it to a command string and read another ReadKey until you have a functional string or Enter is pressed

Comment: Seems your application needs some state management to know whether to run a command or print the keypress and expect more inputs until ENTER is pressed (and then parse & run some other command). Having your code in the post would probably help us help you here.

Comment: I tried to hold `"e"` and add `"cho"` but this makes it impossible to delete the first character and also it is no longer possible to recall the command with up arrow.